# how to solve google compute engine ssl setup 401 error on the certificate

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am using docker compose in my dev env and the project runs. I  thought as long as I had firewall rules set up in the cloud console for the project it would open the ports automatically. [but I needed to run docker with the -p flag]

The vm runs the Dockerfile in the project and opens a container using my image with no ports open.  I have to ssh in stop and remove the container and run a new one on the image with the -p 80:8080 flag set in order to be able to see the site in http.  that seems to work.

I am using a private image for my vm that has the website running when the container starts.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
 FROM golang:1.19.2-alpine3.16
 RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
 USER app
 WORKDIR /app
 RUN mkdir data
 COPY go.mod ./
 COPY go.sum ./
 RUN go mod download
 COPY . . 
 CMD go build -o apps cmd/web/*.go && ./apps -cache=true - 
  production=true
  EXPOSE 80:8080
```

This is the compose file [but it is not part of the image right now]
it is one folder up

```
     version: "3.8"
 services: 
   frontend: 
     build: ./app_links
     ports: 
       - 80:8080
```

Note that this is from google documentation: [and is actually wrong]

> Container ports have a one-to-one mapping to the host VM ports. For example, a container port 80 maps to the host VM port 80. Compute Engine does not support the port publishing (-p) flag, and you do not have to specify it for the mapping to work. To publish a container's ports, configure firewall rules to enable access to the host VM instance's ports. The corresponding ports of the container are accessible automatically, according to the firewall rules.

[google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#publishing_container_ports)

this is what I get back from google on the managed certificate after setting up a frontend & backend service with a health check:

```
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Login Required.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"location": "Authorization",
"locationType": "header"
}
],
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
"domain": "googleapis.com",
"metadatas": {
"method": "compute.v1.SslCertificatesService.Get",
"service": "compute.googleapis.com"
}
```

Comment: Share us your docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add an a record that points to the load balancer's IP address to Google Domains dns setup [Other registrars may be different]